# How to create three node cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is it possible to create cassandra cluster with two data centers?

`dc1 - two node docker containers on the same host
dc2 - one node data center`

When i tried the same, from dc2 it is failing to seed from dc1 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the information you're searching for: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initMultipleDS.html

Basically, you set the DC information in cassandra-rackdc.properties.

Comment: Will two docker cassandra nodes can be exposed with same host ip for other data center nodes to communicate?

Comment: No. You can't use same IP for two hosts. You can't do that in any application since that would remove the whole purpose of having an identifier.